# NSWindow with a hole and mouse events

Tags: cocoa, mouseevent, transparent, nswindow

I am developing an Desktop application in which I am creating a window with a hole in it.

1. The user should be able to drag the window present just below the hole through this hole.
2. When he clicks on the area other than the hole, he should be able to move my window.

I have tried the following:

When user performs mouseDown inside the hole, setIngnoresMouseEvents is set to YES. So, if I click on the area of the window other than the hole, that mouse-event is not taken by my window. It goes to the app whose window could be seen through the hole.

How can I achieve these behaviors?